# Location of tensorflow/models.. in Windows

Tags: python, windows, docker, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow on Windows using Docker, I want to go to the folder "tensorflow/models/image/imagenet" that contains "classify_image.py" python file..
Can someone please how to reach this mentioned path?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using one of the devel tags (`:latest-devel` or `:latest-devel-gpu`), the file should be in `/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py`.

If you're using the base container (`b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`), it's not included -- that image just has the binary installed, not a full source distribution, and `classify_image.py` isn't included in the binary distribution.